# Access Raspberry Pi mySQL Database through a simple html

Tags: php, html, mysql, raspberry-pi

I am working on a simple IoT school project with the Raspberry Pi and a few environments sensors. I used mySQL to store the data. I want to make a simple HTML and PHP to query the data from a device connect to the local network but i don not know how to do it. ( I have read through some android app solution but I wonder if there is a solution in HTML and PHP).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiet way would be to install a lamp stack, which is short for Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP

if you have rasbian installed (debian based) you can do `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

then put php files in `/var/www/html/`

you can access mysql with `mysqli` in php

and then access it by going to typing the pi's ip into a web browser

Comment: it seem it only work on my laptop connect to the rasp by LAN. But my goal it to work with local wifi.

Comment: you'll have to give more details. do you mean the pi will connect to a router with cat cable and then the laptop will connect with wifi? do you mean both the pi and laptop connect to wifi router? or do you mean the laptop connects directly to the pi via wifi? also connecting to it doesn't really have to do with lamp as in the original question you'll need to be much more specific to get a more specific answer.